# Why can Oxford or Dublin (Trinity College) graduates be admitted to the equivalent Cambridge degree?

Tags: degree

What links Cambridge with Trinity College Dublin? I know

1. Oxford and Cambridge are frequently lumped together as Oxbridge,
2. Oxford and Cambridge each have a college called "Trinity College".

[Degrees under Statute B II 2 | Student Registry](https://www.student-registry.admin.cam.ac.uk/graduation/degrees-under-statute-b-ii-2)

> Under Statute B II 2, the M.A. degree may be conferred on Heads and Fellows of Colleges, University officers, and senior staff of the University Press or Cambridge Assessment if they are not already Cambridge graduates. Graduates of the Universities of Oxford or Dublin (Trinity College) may be admitted to the equivalent Cambridge degree instead of the M.A.
>
> Degrees under Statute B II 2 are full degrees conferring the same rights as the equivalent degrees by examination, i.e. permanent membership of the Senate with its associated privileges and entitlement to submit work for other degrees such as the Ph.D. under Special Regulations or for Higher Doctorates such as the Litt.D. or Sc.D. They are not titular ‘honorary degrees’ (which are awarded by a different process).

Comment: Wikipedia explains it in the first paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_College_Dublin. A bit of history that has been preserved.

Comment: If you want to apply, they will decide if and how your qualifications match on a case by case basis.

Comment: They were until the late nineteenth century the only three "English" universities. The four old Scottish universities had a similar mutual recognition and admission "ad eundum gradum" system, at least until the 1960s.